# No configuration files on Solus i3

Tags: linux, i3-window-manager

Well, i recently switched from Mint cinnamon to Solus Os
I am used to I3wm, when i tried to install it and switch to it, it boots normally but the issue is there's no configuration files, and key bindings doesn't work
I have Solus Os with Mate Desktop Environment
I removed lightdm, i boot directly using the startx command
I know i could copy files but it's a bit frustrating because it might generate other issues, any help/advise is welcomed

Answer (score 1):

Silly me, it just had to run a simple command
i3-config-wizard
If anyone had this problem just run the command